# How does UUID work with PHPCassa

Tags: cassandra, uuid, phpcassa

I am using:

```
CassandraUtil::uuid1();
```

This is what I get:

```
ämªðÏBà=0£Ï‰
```

I though it would output a int.

What is going on? Is it normal?

Also should I use uuid1 or 2 or 3 or 4 or ...?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few parts to UUIDs in phpcassa.  First, how to generate one.  The following functions are useful for this:

```
$my_uuid_string = phpcassa\UUID::uuid1();
$my_uuid_string = phpcassa\UUID::uuid4();
```

uuid1() generates a v1 UUID, which has a timestamp component, and is called TimeUUIDType in Cassandra.  uuid4() generates a totally random UUID, and is called LexicalUUIDType in Cassandra.  (The other uuidX() functions aren't generally that useful.)  What this function gives you back is a byte array representation of the UUID -- basically a 16 byte string. This is what your `"ämªðÏBà=0£Ï‰"` string is. When you are trying to insert a UUID into Cassandra, this is what you want to use.

It's possible to make a UUID object which has useful methods and attributes from this byte array:

```
$my_uuid = phpcassa\UUID::import($my_uuid_string);
```

With $my_uuid, you can get a pretty string representation like 'd881bf7c-cf8f-11e0-85e5-00234d21610a' by getting `$my_uuid->string`.  You can get back the byte representation by doing `$my_uuid->bytes`.  Any uuid data that you get back from Cassandra will by in the byte array format, so you need to use `UUID::import()` on it if you want a UUID object.

Also, `UUID::import()` also works on the pretty string representation as well (the one that looks like ''d881bf7c-cf8f-11e0-85e5-00234d21610a').

Last, don't forget about the documentation for the  [UUID class](http://thobbs.github.io/phpcassa/api/class-phpcassa.UUID.html).

**EDIT**: updated links and class names to match the latest phpcassa API

Comment: What do you recommend me to reduce collision?

Comment: Don't worry about collisions. The whole purpose of UUIDs is to make the probability of a collision insignificantly small. If you need something ordered by time, use uuid1(). If you don't, use either uuid4() or uuid1().

Comment: Would you use it to generate users in a website where you need your users to create accounts?

Comment: Yes, if you're using that as a unique user identifier, that's a good idea.

Comment: There is no CassandraUtil in phpcassa for me (for example), use `phpcassa\UUID::uuid{N}()` instead.

Answer (score 4):

`uuid1()` generates a UUID based on the current time and the MAC address of the machine.

- Pros: Useful if you want to be able to sort your UUIDs by creation time.
- Cons: Potential privacy leakage since it reveals which computer it was generated on and at what time.
- Collisions possible: If two UUIDs are generated at the exact same time (within 100 ns) on the same machine.  (Or a few other unlikely marginal cases.)

`uuid2()` doesn't seem to be used anymore.

`uuid3()` generates a UUID by taking an MD5 hash of an arbitrary name that you choose within some namespace (e.g. URL, domain name, etc).

- Pros: Provides a nice way of assigning blocks of UUIDs to different namespaces.  Easy to reproduce the UUID from the name.
- Cons: If you have a unique name already, why do you need a UUID?
- Collisions possible: If you reuse a name within a namespace, or if there is a hash collision.

`uuid4()` generates a completely random UUID.

- Pros: No privacy concerns.  Don't have to generate unique names.
- Cons: No structure to UUIDs.
- Collisions possible: If you use a bad random number generator, reuse a random seed, or are very, very unlucky.

`uuid5()` is the same as `uuid3()`, except using a SHA-1 hash instead of MD5.  Officially preferred over `uuid3()`.

Comment: I am thinking of using uuid1(); But I am worried about collision. What are the ways with PHPCassa that I can eliminate that problem?